# Bootstrap typeahead - Abort selection handler

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using [bootstrap::typeahead](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) for selecting a hidden value by clicking on his label

```
<input name="selected_label" class="typeahead" type="text" />
<input name="selected_value" type="hidden" />
```

I'd like to update the selected_label (revert the previous label) when the user clicks elsewhere to abort the selection.
The aim is to tell the user that he have not selected anything.

Is there an `onclose` handler ?
Or is there an other way to do it ?

Comment: You could do this with jquery and simply listens on the  event when the selected_label loses focus

Comment: Do you have any code example ? I can't figure out how to observe the elsewhere click event and get the just dismissed typeahead input